# Prevent Fotorama autoplay from stopping on click or touch

Tags: jquery, fotorama

I have a Fotorama slideshow that I need the viewer to watch all the way through.  It is currently set to autoplay and to stop on the final slide.  But, when you click on the slideshow or touch it on mobile, the show stops and does not resume.  How do I avoid this?  I tried using data-stopautoplayonthouch="false" but it didn't help.

This is my fotorama:

```
<div class="fotorama"
 data-width="100%"
 data-height="100%"
 data-margin="0"
 data-fit="cover"
 data-nav="none"
 data-autoplay="1500"
 data-arrows="false"
 data-click="false"
 data-swipe="false"
 data-stopautoplayontouch="false">
```

I have also added this to make the show stop on the last slide:

```
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:showend', function (e, fotorama) {
if (fotorama.size - fotorama.activeIndex === 1) {
    fotorama.stopAutoplay();
}
});
```

Any suggestions?

Art, here's an example:

```
<body>

<div class="fotorama"
 data-width="100%"
 data-height="100%"
 data-margin="0"
 data-fit="cover"
 data-nav="none"
 data-autoplay="1500"
 data-arrows="false"
 data-click="false"
 data-swipe="false"
 data-stopautoplayontouch="false">

 <a href="_images/clients.jpg"></a>
 <a href="_images/consulting.jpg"></a>
 <a href="_images/debrief.jpg"></a>
 </div>

<script>'use strict';
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:showend', function (e, fotorama) {
if (fotorama.size - fotorama.activeIndex === 1) {
    fotorama.stopAutoplay();
}
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you show a test case that we could look at and debug?

Comment: I added an example to my original post.  Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a Fotorama bug. Will fix it soon. Track it here: https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/192

Comment: Were you able to fix this Fotorama bug?  If so, how should I update my code?